# Get the value of a Swift Int in objective-c

Tags: swift, objective-c, bridging-header

I want to store the objective-c value of an enum in a Swift class, and later I would like to read it again in objective-c. I constantly get a memory address instead of the value. How can I get the value out of the Swift Int and turn it again into the enum?

```
@objcMembers
public class MyClass: SuperClass {
    public var myNumber: Int
}
```

```
@objc public enum SomeEnum: Int {
    case apple
    case pear
}
```

```
- (void)aDemoFunction:(MyClass *)varname {
   int test = varname.myNumber; //test gets a long number, e.g. -2028686406

// this is what I want to achieve.
// it never works, because already the int is wrong
   SomeEnum myValue = (SomeEnum)varname.myNumber; // expected my enum type, but debugger says it's SomeEnum | 0xa80aa52d8714b3b8
}
```

In objective-c code I access the variable myNumber.
If I print `po varname.myNumber` the result is as expected. Prints "1" for example for pear.

I've tried a lot, e.g.

```
int test = myVariable.myNumber; // (int) test = -2028686406
int test2 = (int)myVariable.myNumber; // (int) test2 = -2028686406
NSNumber *test3 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:myVariable.myNumber]; //NSNumber *) test3 = 0x0000000121480610
```

---

**edit:**
As Rob Napier pointed out, it must somehow be related to something else, because I've created an isolated example and there it just works. Here it is:

MyClass.swift

```
import Foundation

@objc public enum SomeEnum: Int {
    case apple
    case pear
}

@objcMembers
public class MyClass: NSObject {

    public var myNumber: Int = 0

}
```

ViewController.m (~empty header file)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "demo-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyClass *myClassInstanc = [MyClass new];
    NSLog(@"myClassInstanc.myNumber: %ld", (long)myClassInstanc.myNumber); // 0

    myClassInstanc.myNumber = SomeEnumPear;
    NSLog(@"myClassInstanc.myNumber: %ld", (long)myClassInstanc.myNumber); // 1

    SomeEnum myEnum = (SomeEnum)myClassInstanc.myNumber; // 2
    NSLog(@"myClassInstanc.myNumber as enum: %ld", myEnum);

    if(myEnum == SomeEnumPear) {
        NSLog(@"success"); // success is printed
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Please show all the relevant code. I look forward to hearing what "cast the int into the enum" means (eg init(rawValue:) ?)

Comment: Thanks matt, I've edited the question. What I meant with casting was `MyEnum myValue = (MyEnum)varname.myNumber;`

Comment: You've shown us definitions for `MyClass` and `SomeEnum`, but not `MyEnum`. I presume that it's some sort of enum with an associated value, but don't make us guess.

Comment: Argh, corrected it, it's the same enum.

Comment: You're still forcing us to guess what your code looks like. The above code code does not compile. Even putting aside the fact that SuperClass isn't provided, MyClass requires an init. What you're describing is subtle; it's going to based on the *actual code*. Simplify your problem to a tiny project that you can really compile and shows the problem. Don't take snippets from a large project and assume they're identical to a highly simplified, abstract version. Usually when you go to the trouble of making that tiny project, you'll discover the problem yourself.

Comment: Lest there be any confusion: Yes, Swift can transfer trivial Int types to ObjC. We know that works. So your issue is something other than that. (You should be using NSInteger rather than `int` here, but that's likely not the problem.) If you can't transfer the Int, then of course it won't cast properly to an enum. That's no surprise. Make your problem simpler and simpler until it goes away, then you'll know where your problem is. Get rid of the enum. Get rid of all other code. Make it so simple it can't fail. But for us to help, we need real code.

Comment: I see your update where it works. So…yeah. Now you have something that works and something that doesn't and that means you're well on your way. Somewhere between them is the bug. I'd start with your failing code and making it simpler and simpler (rather than starting with the working code and making it more complicated). I often comment out huge parts of the code on the way there. I've had an error like this one, and it was due to passing a bool when compiling in ObjC++ that was a different than the size of BOOL in ObjC because of a header `#if`. It can be weird things.